# Rotate on hover using Jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, rotation

I can't figure out how to set up a jquery rotate function that would only rotate on hover.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$('div.settingsButton').hover(function() {
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        angle += 4;
        $(this).rotate(angle);
    }, 50);
},
function() {
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        angle = 0;
        $(this).rotate(angle);
    }, 50);
});
```

The rotate is a plugin found here:
http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Within your timer function, `this` is not the DOM element. You have to store it in a variable. Also, you should use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) in your `mouseout` function.

Here's some sample code:

```
var timer;

$('div.settingsButton').hover(function() {

    var angle = 0,
        $this = $(this);

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        angle += 4;
        $this.rotate(angle);
    }, 50);
},
function() {

    timer && clearInterval(timer);
    $(this).rotate(0);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptJuU/

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I still cant get this to work? any ideas?

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work on my pc. I copied all of my code into a fiddle and it works their but does not on my computer. here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptJuU/5/

Comment: @Ian34 - Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, both on my computer and on the fiddle

Comment: @Ian34 - I honestly have no idea. Are you sure you are properly loading the rotate plugin? I'm sorry, but there's nothing more I can help you with.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea. Instead I just ended up using CSS3 Transform to rotate it on hover. Oh well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13696/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-ian34)